# Hide the button of logout

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, hide

i'm working on my site, and i want only logged in users will see the button of logout.
but i don't know how to do that, i did it like that in the Masterpage

```
        if (Session["Username"] != null)
        UserName = "Hello :" + Session["Username"].ToString() ;
     <asp:Button ID="Logout" runat="server" Text="Click Here to Logout" CssClass="Logout" OnClick="Logout_Click" />
```

if is working fine, but i don't know hot to put the button there

Comment: put brackets around the last 2 lines

Comment: Is this entire code snippet in the masterpage form or is the top half with the if statement from the code behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok how about trying this in your code behind for your Masterpage:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            if (Session["Username"] != null)
                Logout.Visible = true;

            else
                 Logout.Visible = false;
        }
 }
```

This is assuming you have a your logout button on the form with ID="Logout".

Hope this helps.

Comment: That says "The Name 'Logout' does not exist in the current context'
But it is. 
@Ben

Comment: Hmmm the button is on the master page right? And this code you placed in the code behind of your master page? Could you post the markup of your master page form? @GalIsrael

Comment: Yes, it placed in the right place, and in the master page.
i will upload it to pase bin
masterpage: http://pastebin.com/Am4rZS6E
masterpage.master.cs : http://pastebin.com/RJVFtdJM

Comment: I copied over your code to a new project and I am able to build with the Logout.Visible part uncommented. So this should be working @GalIsrael

Comment: There might be a problem with your designer file where for some reason the button id is spelt incorrectly. @GalIsrael

Answer (score 0):

You also check session and hide logout button on Aspx side by using

```
 <%  if (Session["Username"] != null)
       { %> 
     <asp:Button ID="Logout" runat="server" Text="Click Here to Logout" CssClass="Logout" OnClick="Logout_Click" />
     <%} %>
```